# Refactor nested switch statement on union members using modern C++

Tags: c++, nested, switch-statement

How can I use modern C++ to get the same effect as

```
enum Value_type_id { i, f, d };
union Value { int i; float f; double d; };
struct Item { Value_type_id type; Value value; };

Item add(Item lhs, Item rhs)
{
  Item result;
  switch (lhs.type)
  {
    case i:
      switch (rhs.type)
      {
        case i:
          result.type = i;
          result.value.i = lhs.value.i + rhs.value.i;
          break;
        case f:
          result.type = f;
          result.value.f = lhs.value.i + rhs.value.f;
          break;
        case d:
          result.type = d;
          result.value.d = lhs.value.i + rhs.value.d;
          break;
      }
      break;
    case f:
      switch (rhs.type)
      {
        case i:
          result.type = f;
          result.value.f = lhs.value.f + rhs.value.i;
          break;
        case f:
          result.type = f;
          result.value.f = lhs.value.f + rhs.value.f;
          break;
        case d:
          result.type = d;
          result.value.d = lhs.value.f + rhs.value.d;
          break;
      }
      break;
    case d:
      switch (rhs.type)
      {
        case i:
          result.type = d;
          result.value.d = lhs.value.d + rhs.value.i;
          break;
        case f:
          result.type = d;
          result.value.d = lhs.value.d + rhs.value.f;
          break;
        case d:
          result.type = d;
          result.value.d = lhs.value.d + rhs.value.d;
          break;
      }
      break;
  }
  return result;
}
```

but without having to tediously code the nested switch statement with nearly identical cases for this and other functions of two instances of `Item`?  Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like

```
Item add(Item lhs, Item rhs)
{
  return some_magic_here(std::plus{}, lhs, rhs);
}
```

but I haven't figured out how to implement `some_magic_here`.
Basing `Item` on `std::variant`, and `some_magic_here` on `std::visit`, seemed appropriate at first glance, until I discovered that `std::visit` requires the return value to have the same type for all alternatives represented in the variant.  I need return types that are the `std::common_type` of the two argument types, which isn't always the same.

Actually, my use case has 8 different data types, which leads to 64 different cases that are identical except for which members of the unions are accessed.

Addition 2023-11-11: My application (an implementation of an interpreted language)
is standalone and large (170'000 lines) and uses the enum/union/struct
throughout.  I can (with a lot of work) replace them with something
else, but only wanted to do that if there was clear benefit, such as
getting rid of the many near-duplicate switch cases for the different
supported data types.  The accepted answer (by Miles Budnek) provides that.

Addition 2023-11-15: I now realize that I need a similar solution for vectors, too, but I don't know how to extend the current question's answer to that case, so I've asked a follow-up question here: [Refactor nested switch statement on union members with vectors, using modern C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77487255/refactor-nested-switch-statement-on-union-members-with-vectors-using-modern-c)

Comment: If you look at the example of the code for `std::vist` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) you can see they use a visitor that asserts if the type is not in the variant, which you could do as well.  This looks like a straight up use case for `variant` and `vist`

Comment: You can manually specify the return type of the visitor... If you return `Item`, then what's the problem? Standard conversions should do pretty much what you switch does.

Comment: For example https://wandbox.org/permlink/52gbGJh8Fp5ZeMz5

Comment: Can you replace your enum/union/struct types with something else?   Or are you required to use them (say, for compatibility with other code) and only change the `add()` function?

Comment: @Peter: See my addition of 2023-11-11 above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the visitor passed to `std::visit` has to return the same type for all cases, but there's no reason that type can't itself be a `std::variant`:

```
using Item = std::variant<int, float, double>;

Item add(Item lhs, Item rhs)
{
    return std::visit(
        [](auto lhs, auto rhs) { return Item{lhs + rhs}; },
        lhs,
        rhs
    );
}
```

[Example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d8d70b0e3af71a2)

The return type of the visitor is always `std::variant<int, float, double>`, but that `variant` holds a different type depending on the type contained in `lhs` and `rhs`.