# Refactor nested switch statement on union members with vectors, using modern C++

Tags: c++, vector, nested, switch-statement

This is a follow-up question to [Refactor nested switch statement on union members using modern C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77463208/refactor-nested-switch-statement-on-union-members-using-modern-c), extending it to vectors.  How can I use `std::variant` to get rid of nested switch statements on union members to implement a binary operation on vectors?  My current code (with a very long history) is similar to

```
enum Value_type_id { i, f, d };
union Pointer { int* i; float* f; double* d; };
struct Item { Value_type_id type; Pointer data; size_t element_count; };

// Item::data points at the beginning of a std::vector
// of the appropriate type with the given element_count.

void add(const Item& lhs, const Item& rhs, Item& result)
{
  assert(lhs.element_count == rhs.element_count);
  assert(lhs.element_count == result.element_count);
  // the type of the data values accessible through
  // "result" is the highest of the types of the data
  // values accessible through "lhs" and "rhs".
  auto n = lhs.element_count;
  auto lhsdata = lhs.data;
  auto rhsdata = rhs.data;
  auto resultdata = result.data;
  switch (lhs.type)
  {
    case i:
      switch (rhs.type)
      {
        case i:
          while (n--)
            *resultdata.i++ = *lhsdata.i++ + *rhsdata.i++;
          break;
        case f:         
          while (n--)
            *resultdata.f++ = *lhsdata.i++ + *rhsdata.f++;
          break;
        case d:
          while (n--)
            *resultdata.d++ = *lhsdata.i++ + *rhsdata.d++;
          break;
      }
      break;
    case f:
      switch (rhs.type)
      {
        case i:         
          while (n--)
            *resultdata.f++ = *lhsdata.f++ + *rhsdata.i++;
          break;
        case f:
          while (n--)
            *resultdata.f++ = *lhsdata.f++ + *rhsdata.f++;
          break;
        case d:
          while (n--)
            *resultdata.d++ = *lhsdata.f++ + *rhsdata.d++;
          break;
      }
      break;
    case d:
      switch (rhs.type)
      {
        case i:         
          while (n--)
            *resultdata.d++ = *lhsdata.d++ + *rhsdata.i++;
          break;
        case f:
          while (n--)
            *resultdata.d++ = *lhsdata.d++ + *rhsdata.f++;
          break;
        case d:
          while (n--)
            *resultdata.d++ = *lhsdata.d++ + *rhsdata.d++;
          break;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

This has many nearly identical copies of the same code, differing only in which of the union members is used.  I would like to be able to do something like

```
using Data = std::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<float>, std::vector<double>>;

Data add(const Data& lhs, const Data& rhs)
{
  return some_magic_here(std::plus(){}, lhs, rhs);
}
```

but don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Have a look at [std::visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)

Comment: I have.  I don't know how to apply it here.  I would appreciate an example.

Comment: Have you tried `using Data = std::vector<std::variant<int*,float*,double*>>` instead? I think that makes more sense.

Comment: When I literally copy&paste [the documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit), I’m getting [something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/WPY9h5cGv). Some `const *` versions are [easy to add](https://godbolt.org/z/WMaPb8ovY), if needed. Another interesting option would be lambdas with `auto *` arguments in the `FunctionalStyleVisitor`, which can make it as concise as the `SimpleVisitor`. It’s all about having an `operator ()(Type)` for each `Type` in the `std::variant`.

Comment: @Red.Wave But the nesting would have to be `std::span<std::variant<...`, not vice versa.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek no. This is the word by word translation of the OP struct. `type` tag is shared by the range constituted from `data` pointer and `element_count`. Your suggestion uses one `type` tag per element in `span{data, element_count}`. Notice: `Pointer` does not hold a `type` tag; `Item` does. So `using Item =std::variant<std::span<int>,std::span<float>,std::span<double>>` is what the OP has tried to implement. If it where the opposite, `Pointer` would be a `struct` with a `type` tag, and `Item` would only contain `data` and `element_count`.

Comment: Fixed the typo:`using Item =std::variant<std::span<int>,std::span<float>,std::span<double>>;`

Answer (score 0):

A friend came up with

```
Data add(const Data& lhs, const Data& rhs)
 {
   return std::visit([](auto lhsv, auto rhsv)
   {
     using AddType = decltype(lhsv[0] + rhsv[0]);
     auto count = std::min(lhsv.size(), rhsv.size());
     std::vector<AddType> result(count);
     auto lhsp = lhsv.data();
     auto rhsp = rhsv.data();
     auto p = result.data();
     for (int i = 0; i < element_count; i++)
       *p++ = *lhsp++ + *rhsp++;
     return result;
   }, lhs, rhs);
}
```

This reduces the amount of code enormously.  It still has the binary operation (here addition) hardcoded in, but is already an enormous improvement on the original code.